# Como generar una lista a partir de un vector de lista concatenando subsecuencias de positivos y negtivos

Tags: c++, c++11

Implemente una función
`void sign_join(vector< list<int> > &VL,list<int> &L)` que, dado un vector de listas **VL**
generar una lista **L** donde están
Primero concatenados todos la primera subsecuencia de no-negativos de **VL[0], VL[1]** **, ...**
Después los negativos.
Después nuevamente los no-negativos.
Asi siguiendo hasta que se acaban todos los VL

**Ejemplos:
VL: [[1,2,-1,-2,3,4,-3,-4],[5,6,-5,-6,7,8,-7,-8],[-9,-10]],**

**=> L: [1,2,5,6,-1,-2,-5,-6,-9,-10,3,4,7,8,-3,-4,-7,-8],**

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
int sign(int &x){
    if(x>=0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

bool vectorempty(vector<list<int>> &VL) {
    for(int i=0; i<VL.size(); i++) {
        if(!VL[i].empty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    vector<list<int>> vl = {{1,2,-3}, {3,4,-5,-1}, {5,6,-8}};
    list<int> l;

    int s = 1;
    int i=0;
    while(vectorempty(vl)==false){
        auto it = vl[i].begin();
        while(it != vl[i].end() && sign(*it)==s) {
            l.push_back(*it);
            it=vl[i].erase(it);
        }
        if(i == (vl.size()-1)) {
            i=0;
            s=-s;
        }else{
            ++i;
        }
    }

    for(int &x:l) cout<<x<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Pero queda en un loop infinito y no se como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Sin depurar no consigo ver en qué parte se queda el programa en un bucle infinito (¡por cierto! ¿has intentado depurar?).

---

Sigo pensando que te complicas la vida innecesariamente y reinventas la rueda:  Ya existe una función para determinar si un número es negativo, pertenece a la cabecera [`<cmath>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) y es la función [`std::signbit` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit).

#### Propuesta.

Crea una función separada (para seguir el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica)) que te haga la operación, mi consejo es que no sea una operación destructiva (que no altere los datos originales).

El algoritmo a seguir, en pseudocódigo, sería:

1. Accede a una lista.
2. Extrae números mientras los números sean del signo adecuado (y queden números).
3. Sigue el paso anterior hasta el final o hasta dar con un número de signo inadecuado.
4. Pasa a la siguiente lista, repite hasta que todas las listas estén vacías.

En código podría parecerse a esto:

```
using ilist = std::list<int>;
using vlist = std::vector<ilist>;

ilist procesa(const vlist &vl)
{
    auto negativo = false;
    auto temp = vl;
    auto datos = [](const vlist &vl)
    {
        for (const auto &l : vl)
            if (l.size())
                return true;
        return false;
    };
    ilist resultado{};

    while (cuenta(temp))
    {
        for (auto &lista : temp)
//                ~~~~~~ <--- Accede a la lista
        {
            for (auto v = lista.begin(), e = lista.end();
                (v != e) && (std::signbit(*v) == negativo);)
//              ~~^~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
//                 \--- Mientras queden números     /
//                                                 /
// Mientras los números sean del signo adecuado --/
            {
                resultado.push_back(*v);
                v = lista.erase(v);
//              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Extrae números
            }
        }
        negativo = !negativo;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```